# Low Quality Posts Upvoting Upon Review

Tags: discussion, review

When reviewing low quality posts, you do not have the option to upvote the answer on the review screen.

- There are certainly times when there are issues with the post for a lot of different reasons.
- However, there are actually times when the post is a wonderful, direct and excellent hint. At that point, it would be nice to be able to upvote upon review.

Is there a rationale why you cannot upvote those (which is available on all other review screens) on the review screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a meta.stackexchange.com post ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141145/148069)) by Shog9 ♦:

> The core philosophy here is that each queue focuses on a specific task
>   or question, and provides the tools most important for resolving it.
>   If you want to do something else, **there will always be a prominent
>   link to the full question page**.
>
> A concern with allowing voting in the Low Quality queue specifically
>   is that you're not viewing answers in the context of other answers, or
>   a question in the context of its answers. You're never able to vote in
>   these circumstances normally - it's worth remembering that voting
>   directly from the list of questions was considered early on, and
>   discarded as too likely to produce bad results.

Comment: I find it impossible to make a decision on any review task without looking at the full question page anyway.